# How to convert Oracle REPEAT_INTERVAL to SQL Server msdb.dbo.sysschedules (freq_type, freq_interval)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, job-scheduling

How to convert Oracle REPEAT_INTERVAL to SQL Server msdb.dbo.sysschedules attributes (freq_type, freq_interval, etc..) and visa-versa ?

e.g   if REPEAT_INTERVAL ="FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=18; BYMINUTE=10"
then means freq_type=4 and activestarttype="181000"

but what to do with

```
> FREQ=HOURLY; BYMINUTE=20; 
> FREQ=HOURLY; BYMINUTE=0;
```

BTW. May be you have seen the script for representing  msdb.dbo.sysschedules in Oracle's frequncy format?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to express **hourly + byminute** , as a lot of other Oracle scheduler generators like 'yearly', 'monthly with negative byday' , in the sp_add_jobschedule parameters.